# export html form data to excel

Tags: html, excel, forms

I have googled around and have been unable to crack this nut.  I have a form setup to let my site visitors subscribe to my newsletter. It just sends an email to my email, and I add them to my contacts and just then forward them the newsletter. What I need is to be able to have their contact info placed in an Excel spreadsheet for ease of access to my list of subscribers.  Can this be done with just html ? ( I don't know any js or whatever else could be required)

Comment: You may want to consider embedding a Google form, which has this functionality built-in.

Comment: What OS/web server are you running server-side?

Comment: @Diodeus I prefer to learn how to hand code stuff, and not rely on templates and widgets and whatnot.

Comment: Ok, then you will have to learn a server-side language, such as PHP since this cannot be done on the client alone using HTML.

Comment: @Tony I am using windows 8, filezilla ftp, and godaddy is the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to create a php (or your fav scripting language) script that takes an input and appends it to a csv file.  Then have the html form post to said script.  You could even setup a cronjob that sends you an update copy of your contacts periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually - there IS a way to get the data from your HTML form exported into an Excel spreadsheet.

In your HTML form you'll have to create a separate table (it can be hidden).

And the BIG SECRET IS: 
In the  put id tags and then use a JavaScript to replace the innerHTML with the value of the fields on your form which collect the data you want.

Check out the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MitchinThailand/589C4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fillHidTable(){
    var htqf; //-- hidden field
    var rf; //-- retrieved field
    for ( var i = 1; i < 5; i++ ) {
        rf = "htqf"+i;
        document.getElementById(rf).innerHTML = document.getElementById("Q"+i+"CALC").value;
    }
    tableToExcel('hidTable', 'Analysis Results');
}

var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})()
</script>

<title>HTML Form Data to Excel</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .divCenMid{font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrCenMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrCenTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}
    .allbdrLtMid{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;margin:0;}
    .allbdrLtTop{border:.75pt solid windowtext;color:#000;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;margin:0;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="QMSTable">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "4"> QMS Assessment</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> No</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Criteria</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtMid"> Question</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid"> Score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q1</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Quality Unit Independency</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q1CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q1CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q2</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Apply PICS GMP</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Which GMP regulation do you use?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q2CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q2CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q3</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Deviation or Non-conformance</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q3CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q3CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="allbdrCenTop"> Q4</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Complaint</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <input id="Q4CALC" type="text" value="" class="nobdrCenMid" style="overflow:hidden; width:93% " name="Q4CALC"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="hidTable" style="display: none">
    <table id="testTable">
        <caption>Supplier Risk Analysis</caption>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <colgroup></colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Q1</td>
            <td>Do you have the Quality Unit?</td>
            <td id="htqf1">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q2</td>
            <td>Apply PICS GMP?</td>
            <td id="htqf2">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q3</td>
            <td>Do you have a deviation or non-conformance procedure?</td>
            <td id="htqf3">-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Q4</td>
            <td>Do you have a customer complaint procedure?</td>
            <td id="htqf4">-</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="fillHidTable()" value="Export Data to Excel">
</body>
</html>
```

If you can't figure out the details of how to apply it contact me.